# no 'executable' file generated?

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all
I have a package called "kinectueye" and a node called "kinect_ueye.cpp".
whent I compile it I get this message:

```
Built 39 packages with 0 failures.
```

means that no error but when I want to launch it I get this :

```
Couldn't find executable named kinectueye below /home/jros/kinectueye
```

when I check the bin file I don't find the executable file.
What going wrong !?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182360/no-%27executable%27-file-generated-!/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karl Damkjær Hansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2205/karl-damkj%C3%A6r-hansen/) on 2014-07-02**:
Have you stated add_executable(kinectueye kinect_ueye.cpp) in your CMakeList.txt?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-02**:
Yes the problem it worked before.
Now I solve it look at my answer.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solve it.
It was a problem in my CMakeList and adding libraries.
Thank you

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0